# Multicolored Text Image

Tags: java, text, colors

I'm trying to make a rainbow text creator. So far I can take in the plaintext file, but I am having problems changing each character to it's own color. I am trying to do a classic red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple, and repeat.  I have the RGB values in a list so I can loop through them, so the big question is just how to apply them to each character separately.

Comment: Can you add the code that you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do what you want would be to add a JLabel with each letter to a JPanel.

But a more correct way would be to use [Graphics.drawString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html).  Just change the attributes of the Graphics object before writing each character.

And as nullptr mentioned in a comment, you'll need to use FontMetrics to position each character correctly.

Comment: Take a look at FontMetrics (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) to position each character correctly